How to requests for the permission allowing acces to all file(s) in Kivy?
I tried multiple ways to create a directory in documents using kivy (JiCsingApp, to preserve previous data), but somehow it seems that none of them is right, I always receive the error: [Errno 13] Permission denied. I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this problem. I also receive an error message if I create a simple file. If I manually give the permission, the program runs without an error.
Here comes Python:
#....
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.logger import Logger
from jnius import autoclass
from plyer import storagepath

...

if platform == 'android':
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission, check_permission
    from android.storage import app_storage_path, primary_external_storage_path, secondary_external_storage_path

...

    def build(self):
        self.title = '易經'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Black"
        if platform == 'android':
            self.request_android_permissions()
        else:
            self.store = self.get_store()

        return Builder.load_file('oracle.kv')
    
    def request_android_permissions(self):
        permissions = [Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]
        request_permissions(permissions, self.on_permissions_granted)

    def on_permissions_granted(self, permissions, grants):
        if all(grants):
            self.store = self.get_store()
        else:
            Logger.error("Permissions were not granted.")
            self.exit_app()
    def create_app_directory(self):
        Environment = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
        File = autoclass('java.io.File')

        app_folder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 'JiCsingApp')
        
        if not app_folder.exists():
            if app_folder.mkdirs():
                print(f"Directory {app_folder.getAbsolutePath()} created")
                return app_folder.getAbsolutePath()
            else:
                raise PermissionError(f"Failed to create directory:{app_folder.getAbsolutePath()}")
        else:
            print(f"Directory {app_folder.getAbsolutePath()} already exists")
            return app_folder.getAbsolutePath()
        
    def get_store(self):
        json_file_path = None
        
        if platform == 'android':
            app_directory = app_storage_path()
            try:
            # Call the method to create app directory
                app_directory = self.create_app_directory()
                print(f"App directory created at: {app_directory}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Encountered error during directory creation: {e}")
            try:
            # Call the method to create app directory
                app_directory = os.path.join(storagepath.get_home_dir(), 'JiCsingApp')
                if not os.path.exists(app_directory):
                    os.mkdir(app_directory)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Encountered error during directory creation: {e}")    
            json_file_path = os.path.join(app_directory, 'prophecies.json')
        else:
                # For other platforms (Windows, MacOS, Linux)
            json_file_path = 'prophecies.json'

        Logger.info(f"Using JSON store at: {json_file_path}")
        return JsonStore(json_file_path)
    def on_start(self):
        # Call the initialize_images method when the app starts
        if not self.check_storage_permission():
            self.request_android_permissions()
        self.initialize_images()

    def check_storage_permission(self):
        # Check if the necessary permissions are already granted
        return (check_permission(Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) and 
                check_permission(Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))


And here is my buildozer.spec file (relevant parts as far as I know):
requirements = plyer, jnius, kivy, https://github.com/kivymd/kivymd/archive/master.zip ...

...

# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
# android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18)
android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE


Thanks for anyone, who can help in advance!

Your app's file access issues might be related to Android's newer storage policies. By ensuring that you're following Scoped Storage practices for Android 10+ and using the correct permissions (like MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for Android 11+), you should be able to resolve the permission denied errors.

Use Context.getExternalFilesDir() for app-specific directories that don't require broad permissions.
Request MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for full external storage access on Android 11+.
Ensure permissions are requested properly, and guide the user to enable them if needed.


While technically correct your answer targets Java/Kotlin and not Python/Kivy.

Try this example. It uses the androidstorage4kivy library, which made the app work for me. Don't forget to add it to the requirements. While developing, you can also run the code on the phone using pydroid 3 without needing to package it with buildozer every time. When creating documents, it will place them in Documents/Pydroid instead of Documents/yourapp.
